# Element Criteria Model: filtering by empty values

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

I'm trying to use the Element Criteria Model to retrieve all entries where value `X` or value `Y` is not null?

I can get all entries where values and X *and* Y are not empty but not sure how to achieve this with either X *or* Y being not empty. any thoughts?

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->limit = NULL;

foreach ($fields AS $field) {
    $criteria->$field = ':notempty:';
}

$entries = $criteria->find();
```

This is what I have for *AND* but not sure how best to go about achieving the same query for *OR*.

An equivalent SQL query would be something along lines of `WHERE (X IS NOT NULL && X <> '') OR (Y IS NOT NULL && Y <> '')`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, doesn't seem to be the most elegant but the only way I could achieve this was by carrying out the entries criteria query within my `$fields` loop. So, for example:

```
$entries = [];

foreach ($fields AS $field) {
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->limit = NULL;
    $criteria->$field = ':notempty:';
    $tmpEntries = $criteria->find();

    $entries = array_merge($entries,$tmpEntries);
}
```